# Happy New Year! How About Some Stats?

Tags: discussion

Since it seems like every website is doing some sort of year end review, I was wondering if some awesome mod would generate some 2014 stats for us:

- Most Viewed Question
- Most Upvoted Question
- Most Upvoted Answer
- Number of new users
- Most active ( or productive? ) new user of 2014
- Current number of active Users

That's just a start off the top of my head but I think it would be cool to see some end of year stats.

Comment: I am sucker for numbers, but I need to note that you don't actually need mod for this. Any mod-specific stats we got access to we are not allowed to share. There is however more than enough numbers going around without that. I'll poke over your suggestions on weekend.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Traffic

The site had received a total of **17 millions page views** in 2014.

### Questions & Answers

There has been over **14 thousands new questions**.

- The most voted new question — **[What is your best practice to execute one-time scripts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/131697/847)** (15 votes)
- The most viewed new question — **[Allow HTML in excerpt](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/141125/847)** (8300+ views).

There has been over **13 thousands new answers**.

The most upvoted new answers — **[guide to excerpts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141136/847)** and **[email sanitization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169368/847)** (18 votes each).

### Users

Approximately **15 thousands new users** were created, bringing it to **45 thousands users total**.

**503 users in total actively participated**, earning more than 50 reputation points.

The most productive new user — **[bonger](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/57034/bonger)**, who wrote **51 answers** and earned **1129 points**.

The most productive user of the year — **[Pieter Goosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen)**, who wrote **594 answers** and earned **12218 points**.

#### Sources

- [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/wordpress.stackexchange.com)
- [Site search *created:2014*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2014)
- [Stack Exchange API / users](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users)
- [Reputation leagues / 2014](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/42/year/wordpress/2014-01-01)

Comment: Thanks Rarst! I find it weird we got more new users than new questions.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee number of questions _at the moment_ might be less than created overall. They get closed, cleaned up, etc. I am not completely sure on number of users created. 15K is what I got from API, but it seems high.

Comment: Just to note: the [StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/wordpress/queries) is a fun tool to play with and get information from. BTW lets pity a world where a (random) collection of numbers counts as statistics for a split second. No insult against this answer intended, you've got my upvote days ago.

Comment: @ialocin the question asked for stats, not statistics ;)

Comment: In my understanding and AFAIK *stats* is the abbreviation of *statistics* - so in my mind it is the same really; like it should be. Besides I'm guessing you exactly know, what common phenomenon and mistake I'm talking about. Anyhow, I probably should bite my tongue some times and forgo more or less unrelated remarks like this.. :)